# Should a context object work when used without 'with'?

Tags: python-3.x, contextmanager

I'm not quite sure how to implement a context manager for a custom class. Basically it's just accepting a file name in `__init__`, opening the file in `__enter__` and closing it in `__exit__`.

E.g., like:

```
class BlaFile:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name

    def __enter__(self):
        self.file = open(self.file_name, "rb")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.file.close()

    def do_stuff_with_file():
        # This will fail when I'm using this class without 'with'.
        return self.file.read(1)
```

However, when I'm not going to instantiate / use the class with the 'with' statement, I will not be able to use any functions of it which access the file, as `__enter__` has never been called; and thus the file is not open.

Maybe I'm too much oriented towards C#'s `using` keyword here; but shouldn't I be able to correctly use an instance of the class even when I'm not using it with the `with` keyword? Right now I'm forced to use it with it - is that the typical usage in Python?

Comment: Put the opening in `__init__` and do nothing in `__enter__`.

Comment: @zondo: That was a thought I had; but is that common to not do something in `__enter__` if I want to be able to use it without `with`? (I'm sorry, I'm still relatively new to Python, and I don't know if other well-known classes do it this way).

Comment: It isn't good practice to use a file without a `with` statement, but the `open` function does allow it.  I couldn't tell you how they implement it.  You might want to register `self.__exit__()` to run when the program exits (the `atexit` module)  just in case the user forgets to do it himself.

Comment: It would be quite interesting how they did it. Anyway, if it's not possible to it like them easily, I'd go with your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the file to be opened regardless of whether or not it is used in a `with`, you need to open the file in your `__init__` method.  Since the user might forget to close the file, I would suggest that you register the closing to happen at exit:

```
from atexit import register

class BlaFile:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.file = open(file_name, 'rb')
        register(self.file.close)

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.file.close()

    def do_stuff_with_file(self):
        return self.file.read(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use open()
to open with reading you need to change to:

```
class BlaFile:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.file = open(self.file_name, "r+b")
    def close(self):
        self.file.close()

    def do_stuff_with_file(self):
        return self.file.read(1)
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: And I can still use it with `with BlaFile("xyz.abc") as bla_file:` when not having `__enter__` and `__exit__`?